# Change image from image folder on button click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, image, visual-studio

I would like to change image on button click. Basically I will let a user upload an image to the folder and when a button is clicked it will go to the next image in the folder when the previous button is click it will go back one image I have done something similar with switch statements, however I knew what images were in the folder making it easy to do that. My code for that is below:

```
  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (Image1.ImageUrl)
            {
                case "image1":
                    Image1.ImageUrl = "image2";
                    break;
                case "image2":
                    Image1.ImageUrl = "image3";
                    break;:
                default:
                    break;
            }
}
```

This worked because I knew exactly what images were in the folder. The code I am trying to make Idk what images may be uploaded to the folder but would like to go through those as well with a button click.

Comment: You could rename the files on upload or store the folder contents in a Array or List.

Comment: i have them stored in listview would it work with that?

Comment: No because a ListView does not "store" items, it only displays them. You need to manipulate the source data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Directory.GetFiles()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get an array of all the filenames in your image directory. Let's call that `myImageArray`.

When you have the filename of the image currently displayed, [Array.IndexOf()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx) will tell you what position that file comes in the array. Let's call it n. Now `myImageArray[n + 1]` will give you the name of the next file.

I will leave it up to you to ensure you don't try to find another filename when you reach the last one.

As it says in the notes to Directory.GetFiles(), it's not guaranteed that the filenames will come out in any particular order. So you will need to use [Array.Sort()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc(v=vs.110).aspx) before looking into it. And if your directory contains other files that are not images, you can use a filter as a second parameter. For example if you only want to cycle through `.jpg` files, do something like this:

```
var myImageArray = Directory.GetFiles("/my/path", "*.jpg");
Array.Sort(myImageArray);
int currentIndex = Array.IndexOf(myImageArray, Image1.ImageUrl);
// etc
```